# Add patch that define own font to a command

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts, xpatch

Can a new patch be added to the `\mathit` command to use fonts that are not controlled by math mode.

I want math mode to use **TeX Gyre Termes Math** and **v** controlled by `\mathit` to use **Computer Modern**

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\showoutput
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\RequirePackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}


\begin{document}

${v}_v＝\mathit{v}_0$,$x＝\textit{v} _0t$\par

$v_x=v_0$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `range` option of `unicode-math`.

Comment: @Cicada I don't seem to understand what you mean. The solution you give can only distinguish fonts by character dimension, but I want to use different fonts when native **math mode** and ```\mathit{}``` render the same character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `\DeclareMathAlphabet` or `\setmathfontface`. But you must do it late or unicode-math will overwrite the setting again.

Pay attention what you input, the equal sign you used doesn't exist in the math font and the log has a missing character message:

```
Missing character: There is no ＝ (U+FF1D) in font TeXGyreTermesMath:
```

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}

\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{TU}{lmr}{m}{it}}
% or 
%\AtBeginDocument{\setmathfontface\mathit{lmroman10-italic}}
\begin{document}

$v＝\mathit{v}$ $v = \mathit{v}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's worked.Thanks for your answer and warning.